# JPA/Hibernate Difference MappedSuperclass and Entity Abstract Class

Tags: database, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I would like to know what is the difference between `MappedSuperclass` and `Entity Abstract Class` when one wants to derive from a super class in `Hibernate`. I know that `Hibernate` does not create a Table in the Database for a `MappedSuperclass`. I read in the `JavaEE` doc *"Abstract entities are like concrete entities but cannot be instantiated"*. Since they cannot be instantiated, I deduce that there is **no matching Table** in the Database. Am I right?

If so, what are virtually the difference between using a `MappedSuperclass` and an `Entity Abstract Class` and what is the impact on the Software and in the Database in each case?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A MappedSuperclass uses inheritance for field and code reuse. For example, if you want all your entities to have a `Long id` and a `Long version` field, you could make them all extend a `BaseEntity` class annotated with `MappedSuperclass` containing these two fields, along with their getters, setters, etc. But you would never have an entity having an association with a BaseEntity: the association would always be with a specific subclass of BaseEntity.

A parent entity is used for "entity polymorphism". For example, you could imagine having two kinds of `Message`: an `EmailMessage` and a `SmsMessage`. Both would contain a source, a target, and a body. But EmailMessage would have an email address and a subject, whereas SmsMessage would have a phone number.

And you could imagine having a `Person` entity containing a collection of sent messages, of type `Message`. The collection would in fact contain instances of EmailMessage and of SmsMessage. Hibernate would decide which one to instantiate depending on the inheritance strategy used for the inheritance mapping:

- all the messages could be stored in the same table, and Hibernate would use a discriminator column containing the type of the message
- the EmailMessage could be stored in one table, and the SmsMessage stored in another one
- or the fields common to both entities (source, target, body) could be stored in a comon table, the fields specific to EmailMessage in a second table, and the fields specific to SmsMessage in a third table.

Comment: @JB Nizet  thanks for your replay, this is exactly what i need, a collection of Messages, but then i need to get specified type entity, i thought about using a map collection to use it like map.get('email') ,  supposing that the person have only one message from each type( requirement may change by the client in the future to have multiple email messages..)