# Why doesn't JPA's EntityManager#getReference return subclass of @MappedSuperclass?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

Given the following contrived JPA entity inheritance relationship:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "SUB_TYPE")
abstract class SuperEntity

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("SUB")
class SubEntity extends SuperEntity
```

Why doesn't the following method call return an instance of class `SubEntity`?

```
EntityManager em;
Long idOfSub = 42;
SuperEntity subAsSup = em.getReference(SuperEntity.class, idOfSub);
```

What is the rationale behind this unexpected behavior? What substitute code would work as expected?

Clarification: I actually don't want to make the (possibly hard-coded) decision of whether I expect an instance of class `SubEntity` or some other type of sub entity to be returned. The client code in my real-world scenario communicates through the API of class `SuperEntity` and doesn't care what concrete type of sub entity it is.

Comment: SuperEntity is not an entity. It's a MappedSuperclass. So the Inheritance and DiscriminatorColumn annotations are useless. If you want it to be an entity, you need to annotate it with Entity. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634048/jpa-hibernate-difference-mappedsuperclass-and-entity-abstract-class

Comment: I've read the other question you referred to. So are you saying that I should annotate the `@MappedSuperclass` `SuperEntity` with `@Entity` too in order to achieve the entity polymorphism I'm after?

Comment: Yes, if you want entity polymorphism, then SuperEntity must be an entity.